# Using jsoup I try to get text using selector path but the "table" element which is in the middle of the path acts like it has 0 elements inside

Tags: java, jsoup

This is the site I'm working on: http://rozklady.mpk.krakow.pl/?lang=PL&rozklad=20180520&linia=1

Text I want to extract: [screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IrPeW.jpg)

This is the code I wrote:

```
    import java.io.IOException;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;


public class fetch_bus_stops {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://rozklady.mpk.krakow.pl/?lang=PL&rozklad=20180520&linia=1").userAgent("Mozilla/17.0").get();
            int i=0;
            int k=0;                       
            Elements select = doc.select("body > table > tbody > tr > td > table > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(1) > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td > table > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(0) > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td > table > tbody");
            int size = select.size();
            System.out.println("Elements size: " + size);
            for(Element row : select)
            {
                String string = String.format("tr:nth-child(" + Integer.toString(k) + ") > td:nth-child(0) > a > span");
                i++;
                k++;
                System.out.println(i+" "+row.select(string).text());
            }
            }
         catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }

}
```

The problem is the loop isn't working size of "select" is 0, I checked the size of select element by element and with the 4th "table" element suddenly size of "select" = 0, why is that? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
.main > tbody:nth-child(2) > tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(1) > table:nth-child(1) > tbody:nth-child(1) > tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(2) > table:nth-child(1) > tbody:nth-child(1) > tr:nth-child(2) > td:nth-child(1) > table:nth-child(1) > tbody:nth-child(1) > tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(1) > table:nth-child(1) > tbody:nth-child(1) > tr:nth-child(2) tr
```

output:

```
0
<tr>
Wzgórza Krzesławickie
1
<tr>
Jarzębiny
2
<tr>
Darwina
3
<tr>
Wiadukty
4
<tr>
Wańkowicza
5
<tr>
Cienista
6
<tr>
Teatr Ludowy
7
<tr>
Rondo Kocmyrzowskie im. Ks. Gorzelanego
8
<tr>
Bieńczycka
9
<tr>
Rondo Czyżyńskie
10
<tr>
Centralna
11
<tr>
Rondo 308. Dywizjonu
12
<tr>
M1 Al. Pokoju
13
<tr>
TAURON Arena Kraków Al. Pokoju NZ
14
<tr>
Plaza
15
<tr>
Dąbie
16
<tr>
Ofiar Dąbia
17
<tr>
Fabryczna
18
<tr>
Francesco Nullo
19
<tr>
Teatr Variété
20
<tr>
Rondo Grzegórzeckie
21
<tr>
Hala Targowa
22
<tr>
Starowiślna
23
<tr>
Poczta Główna
24
<tr>
Plac Wszystkich Świętych
25
<tr>
Filharmonia
26
<tr>
Jubilat
27
<tr>
Komorowskiego
28
<tr>
Salwator
29
<tr>
Salwator
```

Parsing that page will be a challange.
However IMHO it would be better to locate some landmarks and then navigate to neighbors.

For example

```
td:containsOwn(przystanki)
```

would give you required "header" row

from there you could navigate 3 parents up and to second row.

Comment: Where did you type this path which you provided? Because I copy it into doc.select but it doesn't seem to work.